# Is it possible to get (current) system OS styling for web site

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to get CSS styling for some web site elements (like for buttons) that are equivalent to look and feel of a OS (windows, macOS, linux) button style. So every time that I change theme on my windows/mac/linux machine, HTML buttons automatically also changes their CSS style.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#css-system will get you the colors, if the browser supports them.

Comment: It looks like it is deprecated

Comment: Interesting. It is indeed (although that doesn't necessarily mean it's not available for use), and it points people at CSS3's `appearance` property, which was removed early on in the spec's existence. I think I'll write to the mailing list and see if that can be corrected. For your question, I'm guessing you're out of luck, since the browser is not informed of changes to OS theme.

Comment: It looks like I am out of luck

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JavaScript and some useragent sniffing. For example:

```
var useragent = navigator.userAgent;

if (useragent.match(/Foo/g)) {
    //Show useragent-specific content
}

else if (useragent.match(/Bar/g)) {
    //Repeat it for every useragent you want
}
else {
    //everything else
}
```

It will require some time, though

Comment: I would like to have somthing like this: button{color: use-system-style}

Comment: The string specified by the User Agent is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: That value has been **deprecated** in CSS3, so i wouldn't reccomend to use it.

Comment: I think your comment was directed at my comment on the question, not this answer, is that correct?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it was directed to  _
 
I would like to have somthing like this: button{color: use-system-style} – Slit 15 hours ago _ this comment